# Redefine data area for faster access

Tags: c++

New to c++.  I've searched but probably using wrong terms.

I want to find which slot in an array of many slots a few bytes long literal value is stored.  Currently check each slot sequentially.

If I can use an internal function to scan the whole array as if it was one big string, I feel this would be much faster.  (Old COBOL programmer).

Any way I can do this please?

Comment: Are you familiar with a `std::vector`? It will guarantee sequential storage of your data in memory. Also, please provide a code sample.

Comment: if you want everything treated like a big string why not use `std::string` ?

Comment: `std::sort` even works with arrays like you have them.

Comment: Do you have any evidence this is the bottleneck in your code?  My gut feel is that linear search will be as good as you can get (unless you can sort or something like that).

Comment: take a look to containers: `std::vector`, `std::map`, `std::list`, ....

Comment: some questions: 1: are the literals all the same length? 2: can you sort the 'slots' lexographically? 3: is this slot arrangement (we would say 'array of strings') mutable or immutable?

Comment: Sounds like pattern matching. KMP to the rescue?

Comment: I will regress to the bad old "you are asking completely wrong question". Would you post the like-of input data, and what you are trying to achieve, with what algorithms, then maybe somebody may post how to get close to optimal data structures for that particular task. It's unclear to me what is your problem and what you are asking. Bear in mind the C++ compiles quite nicely (directly) to raw machine code, so what you write in the source has direct impact how the data will be laid out in the memory, thus affecting the performance a lot. Without source it's hard to discuss any implications.

Comment: Wow, what a response. I'm extremely grateful to everybody. I will be exploring every answer for learning purposes, but for replying to questions purposes...

Comment: I can't post the code for copyright reasons (trying to tune someone else's  code, mostly as a learning exercise, but affects many people). Bottleneck? If i initialise a 100 item 13 char / item array , a loop looking up the slot executes 25% faster with the matching value in the first slot than the last...

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find which slot in an array of many slots a few bytes long literal value is stored. Currently check each slot sequentially.

OK, I'm going to take a punt and infer that:

1. you want to store string literals of any length in some kind of container.
2. the container must be mutable (i.e. you can add literals at will)
3. there will not be duplicates in the container.
4. you want to know whether a string literal as been stored in the container previously, and what "position" it was at so that you can remove it if necessary.
5. the string literals will be inserted in random lexicographical order and need not be sorted.

The container that springs to mind is the `std::unordered_set`

```
#include <unordered_set>
std::unordered_set<std::string> tokens;

int main()
{
    tokens.emplace("foo");
    tokens.emplace("bar");
    auto it = tokens.find("baz");
    assert(it == tokens.end());   // not found
    it = tokens.find("bar");      // will be found
    assert(it != tokens.end());
    tokens.erase(it);             // remove the token
}
```

The search time complexity of this container is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out by the comments, "scanning as one big string" is not the way to go in C++.

Typical in C++ when using C-style arrays and normally fast enough for linear search is

```
auto myStr = "result";
auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 
                       [myStr](const char* const str) { return std::strcmp(mystr,str) == 0; });
```

Remember that string compare function stop at the first wrong character.

More C++ style:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec = { "res1", "res2", "res3" };
std::string myStr = "res2";
auto it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), myStr);
```

If you are interested in very fast lookup for a large container, `std::unordered_set` is the way to go, but the "slot" has lost its meaning then, but maybe in that case `std::unordered_map` can be used.

```
std::unordered_set<std::string> s= { "res1", "res2", "res3" };
std::string myStr = "res2";
auto it = s.find(myStr);
```

All code is written as example, not compiled/tested